# How to remove faucet on American standard with no screw or cap

Tags: faucet, american-standard

I can’t for the life of me find any screw or cap on this thing. It has been leaking like crazy and  I need to check and/or replace cartridge.

It is an American Standard, that’s all I know. Probably about ten years old. Can’t figure out the model or find the literature from purchase.

Any help? Please?

[image]

Comment: When you turn the valve with the handle does the conical element below the handle turn with the handle or does it stay fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Modern American Standard 4" center-set lav faucets with lever style handle typically have a set-screw at the base of each lever in the back. It may be difficult to see the small screw hole as there is usually a little cover plug that needs to be pried out with a small screwdriver or similar tool. You will need a hex wrench:

[image]

Another style (less common in my experience) simply requires a firm pull upwards for handle removal:

[image]

If this works, here is a link to the complete [installation manual](https://www.americanstandard-us.com/-/media/sites/asus/files/product-instruction-manuals/bulk/installation7038201.pdf?la=en).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately there is absolutely no screw hole anywhere — not open or under a cap or cover. Have thoroughly inspected it. What are the other options?

Comment: See edited answer.